# Adding content from file with wp post create

Tags: wp-cli

I thought I had seen something like this documented where you could pipe in content to a wp-cli arg like so:

`wp post create --post_type=page --post_title="Blah" --post_content= < content.txt`

I tried it and it didn't work, however. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

OK, solution was buried in the command help.

Basically, just drop the --post_content arg and replace with the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
wp post update 271 ~/desktop/my-post.html
```